# SDL cannot read input from keyboard

Tags: c++, io, sdl-2

I am having trouble dealing with input from the keyboard. Somehow all the letter ones are extremely slow(always a big delay), most of the time it just doesn't load at all. But the up down left right and number keys all work really well. Does anyone know why?

This is my program:

```
while (!quit)
            {
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0 )
                {
                    SDL_StartTextInput();
                    //User requests quit
                    switch (e.type) {
                    case SDL_QUIT:
                        quit = true;
                        break;
                    case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
                        if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
                            std::cout << "w ";
                        break;
                    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                        if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_1)
                            std::cout << "1 ";
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: This code never checks whether event type is actually a keyboard input event.

Comment: Or if it's a key down or a key up, or anything really. And you shouldn't be checking the low level events anyway, use event handlers instead.

Comment: @Blindy Does SDL provide event handlers?

Comment: Oh, oops, I was thinking of glfw. My bad, carry on!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in your comments, you never check the event type.
`event.type` can be `SDL_TEXTINPUT` or `SDL_KEYDOWN` for example.

Here I have a typical event loop copied from one of my projects:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        SDL_StartTextInput();
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            appRunning = false;
            break;
        case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
            // here you can use event.text.text; to
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            char keyDown = event.key.keysym.scancode;
            break;
        }
}
```

Here is the official list of SDL_Events: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Event

Comment: For some reason it still doesnt work. I have adjusted the code to this:
while (!quit)
   {
    frameStart = SDL_GetTicks();
    //Handle events on queue
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0 )
    {
     SDL_StartTextInput();
     //User requests quit
     switch (e.type) {
     case SDL_QUIT:
      quit = true;
      break;
     case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
      if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
       std::cout << "w ";
      // here you can use event.text.text; to
      break;
     case SDL_KEYDOWN:
      if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_1)
       std::cout << "1 ";
      break;
     }

Answer (score -1):

SDL provides event handlers for keyboard input.

```
  SDL_Event e;
  .
  .
  /* Poll for events. SDL_PollEvent() returns 0 when there are no  */
  /* more events on the event queue, our while loop will exit when */
  /* that occurs.                                                  */
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
    /* We are only worried about SDL_KEYDOWN and SDL_KEYUP events */
    switch(event.type){
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        //Keypress
        break;

      case SDL_KEYUP:
        //Key Release
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
```

Then, you can get the value of `key->keysym.sym` for the keyboard input.

Comment: SDL_TEXT_INPUT is the better thing to look for. Doing manual key track is a bit over the top, as you have to map key presses to the actual keyboard which then requires detecting the keyboard type and mapping shift / control keys to the actual character (What is <Shift> <4>? depends on the keyboard also depends on the current locale).